# SharePoint Online Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api, pnp-js-core

How could I filter by range in a managed property of type number in a sharepoint search?

I'm using pnp-js-core

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the search result source I just use "greater than" and "less than" for the field in question, works for both numbers and date.  Perhaps this answer could be usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49307394/23499